# Eliminar un dato de la base de datos que se envia por formulario

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, controller, crud

Espero poder hacerme entender.

Tengo un formulario el cual envía ciertos datos a la DB(nombre, dni, telefono, ciudad, etc) y también tiene un campo llamado Beca, el cual debe comprobar si el número que se envía en ese campo existe en la DB y si existe borrarlo para que no pueda volver a utilizarse y al hacerse la comprobación exitosamente deja avanzar, sino enviar alert o aviso de que no existe.
En principio debería no insertarlo y crear una tabla nueva con esos números de Beca. Lo estoy haciendo en Laravel, por ahora tengo ésto en el controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {



        $this->validate($request, [
            'dni'=>'required|unique:future_leaders',
            'phone'=>'required|unique:future_leaders',
            'email'=>'required|unique:future_leaders',
            'enrollment'=>'unique:future_leaders'
            ]); 
            
        
    
        $dataFuture=request()->except('_token', 'scholarship');
        

        future_leaders::insert($dataFuture);
        return view('success');
        return view('futureLeaders')->with('mensaje', "Hemos registrado su solicitud. La inscripción no garantiza admisión al curso. En caso de ser admitido lo notificaremos via mail");
    }
```

Comment: A ver, en principio puedo guardar ese dato que está viajando por POST y compararlo con uno de los registros que tengo ya insertado en la DB

Comment: Por favor considera explicar mejor tu duda pues es un tanto confuso lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta BetaM, a ver si puedo hacerme entender mejor. Lo que ingrese en el campo Beca del form debería compararse con datos que yo tengo cargado en la DB, los cuales tendrían que estar precargados, seguramente en una tabla independiente. Si ese dato que ingresa es igual a uno de los que está en la DB, además de no agregarse, se elimina para que no se pueda volver a utilizar, se entendió mejor?